# Ramda: How to keep the original structure with filter function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want to do a filter function as shown below:

Configuration:

```
const arr = {
  id: 888,
  name: 'Library',
  bookLists: [{
      "name": "Book 1",
      "booked": "Y"
    }, {
      "name": "Book 2",
      "booked": "N"
    }, {
      "name": "Book 3",
      "booked": "Y"
    }]
  };
```

Then I tried to filter the book list with flag 'booked === Y'

```
R.compose(R.filter(x => x.booked === 'Y'), R.prop('bookLists'))(arr)
```

I got the result and it is correct

```
[{"booked": "Y", "name": "Book 1"}, {"booked": "Y", "name": "Book 3"}]
```

However, it is part of what i want. How can i achieve the result like this?

```
{
  id: 888,
  name: 'Library',
  bookLists: [{
      "name": "Book 1",
      "booked": "Y"
    }, {
      "name": "Book 3",
      "booked": "Y"
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R.evolve`:

```
R.evolve({bookLists: R.filter(x => x.booked === 'Y')})(arr)
```

The result will be:

```
{
  id: 888,
  name: 'Library',
  bookLists: [{
      "name": "Book 1",
      "booked": "Y"
    }, {
      "name": "Book 3",
      "booked": "Y"
    }]
  }
```

See the relevant DOCS [here](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve).

Comment: `evolve` is the function best tailored to your needs, but look also at the -- more generic -- `lens` functions: in this case `lensPath` and `over`.